# How to assign Vim's showbreak a value locally to a buffer?

Tags: vim

How can I assign `showbreak` a value **locally** to a buffer? The following makes it +++ for all buffers.

```
let &showbreak="+++"
```

I can set Vim options locally to a buffer by using `setlocal` instead of `set`. I was wondering if there is a way to this with internal variables as well, if there is available some kind of *letlocal, so to speak.

Comment: `'showbreak'` is a plain option, not an internal variable. You're just using the `:let &...` syntax to modify it; `:set` would work just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `:help 'showbreak'`:

```
'showbreak' 'sbr'   string  (default "")
                    global
```

The `global` means that there's no buffer- or window-local value.

You have to either

- Work around this with a set of `:autocmd`s that switch the option based on the entered buffer. However, if you have multiple buffers in split windows, the other ones will also show the changed value. This is similar to the frequent request of having different colorschemes per buffer.
- Write a patch that turns the global option into supporting local values, so that you can `:setlocal` them, or convince someone on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php) to implement such feature.